# Relation between classical and quantum explanations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

It is said that the classical world emerges from the quantum world, but would it be more reasonable to say that the classical explanation is the limit of the quantum one, whilst the quantum explanation is the extrapolated limit of the classical one?

Extrapolated classically because the sun isn't guaranteed to rise tomorrow in a quantum world. Extrapolated quantumly, at the very least, because of the quantum Zeno effect.

In short, can the relationship of the quantum and the classical be described as dependently originated, in line with pratītyasamutpāda?

Comment: Voting to close this question as it isn't clear what you are asking. Moreover, your question seems to be very concerned with concepts from mysticism which is not a part of mainstream physics.

Comment: *"concepts from mysticism"* Care  to explain?

Comment: @Gert The notion of _"pratītyasamutpāda"_, on which the OP anchored their question via summarizing the question in the last line in relation to that notion, is what I refer to when I say _"concepts from mysticism"_. It is a notion arising from and discussed mainly in _Buddhism_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da. Also, I am sure you are more aware than me of this but kindly tag a user if you are addressing them on someone else's post--otherwise they don't get notified.

Comment: See also  Correspondence Principle: *"QM is necessary for the description of nature on the atomic scale, but Newton's laws do fine for baseballs. Somewhere along the continuum from quantum to classical, the two descriptions must merge. Starting from the quantum end and noting that energies depend upon some quantum number, one would anticipate that for high enough quantum numbers, the quantum treatment should merge with the classical. This idea of the merging of the quantum and classical is called the "correspondence principle""* http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hosc6.html#c1

Comment: @DvijMankad: Hi. Sorry, I didn't see that bit, my bad. Have you actually voted?

Comment: @Gert Yeah, I have. It's true that I usually comment before actually voting--but I try to remember to vote then :P

Answer (score 1):

No, Quantum Mechanics cannot be extrapolated **from** Classical Mechanics. There is no classical equation that predicts quantum effects.

---

On the other hand, in quantum mechanics we have more fundamental **Ehrenfest's Theorem**

$$
\bigg\langle \frac{d\hat{p}}{dt} \bigg\rangle = - \bigg\langle\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \bigg\rangle
$$

which indeed predicts Newton's second laws in the classical limit.